# riscv csr unrecognized opcode error when compiling linux kernel

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, riscv

I am trying to install linux kernel 5.15 for riscv64. I get the below message -

```
./arch/riscv/include/asm/vdso/gettimeofday.h:71: Error: unrecognized opcode `csrr a5,0xc01', extension `zicsr' required
./arch/riscv/include/asm/vdso/gettimeofday.h:71: Error: unrecognized opcode `csrr a5,0xc01', extension `zicsr' required
```

I get similar problem trying to compile opensbi v0.9 (mentioning here if the same solution will solve both) -

```
/mada/users/bharsh/cpu_design/dromajo/masc/run/opensbi/lib/sbi/sbi_tlb.c:175: Error: unrecognized opcode `fence.i', extension `zifencei' required
```

I am using riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc for compilation.
Can anyone help resolve this ? Thanks

Comment: Don't know much about RISC-V, but it looks like the kernel build system is not passing the appropriate options to GCC to enable `zicsr` and `zifencei`, see: https://www.reddit.com/r/RISCV/comments/tq396c/missing_zicsr_instructions/ might help.

Comment: This is a toolchain problem. Make sure your compiler was build with the `zicsr` extension.

Answer (score -1):

add **-march=rv32i_zicsr** to cflags

Comment: 0P is clear about building for riscv64